# Bypass the Timer FM-DS3(e) on Hyundai heater

Tags: electrical, heater, timer

I have the oil heater Hyundai with mechanical Timer FM-DS3(e).
I want to baypass the timer. Let the energy go on the heater.
Looks like energy (red)cabel comes to 4 and one part of (white) cabel comes to 1.
Any help will be appreciated.
[image: Timer]

[image]

Comment: looks like white (to 1) is neutral, 3 is the live input (bridged to 2) and 4 is the switched live output, 5 would be the inverted output according to the label.

Comment: thanks for answer.. 
So, should I change red cable from 4 to 5 to bypass timer?

Comment: Changing the cable from 4 to 5 should reverse the normal behavior, which may or may not be what you want. To COMPLETELY bypass the timer, the simplest answer would be to  buy or construct a jumper that let you simply connect the two red wires together. ***BUT BEFORE DOING SO*** make sure you won't also be disabling any safety circuitry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the datasheet for the switch:
http://www.maxtronictech.com/MT-010x02.pdf

The easiest thing to do would be to get a slightly different FM DS(3) that has an on/off/timer switch, and set it to on. Problem solved, no wiring changes.

The second easiest thing would be to turn all the timer switches to the 'on' position.

The third easiest thing to do would be to bridge 3 and 4 with a jumper.  However, then there would be no way to turn this off -- not what you'd usually use for a heater!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There's no need to buy a new time - my is also with the switcher. But this switch does not do what I described here.
I wanted to bypass timer. i.e. do not push the energy on its "ticking mechanism"..
The third way seems to be good, but there should be a way to do smth with the timer.
Please, tell what the "jumper" is?

(p.s. Actually I have a heat control mechanism(0-100%) - connected after the timer)

Comment: If you really want to bypass the entire thing:
Unplug the wire to #1, and put electrical tape over the spade connector.

Unplug wire #3 and wire #4, and either purchase a switch with two spade connectors and connect #3 and #4 to it or cut the spade connectors off #3 and #4 and join them either with a wire nut or a crimped butt connector.

Comment: Didn't you open the module to photograph the electronics inside? This looks like a thermostat, because it doesnt have a timer dial on it. I would have opened it and seen if there is a way to block/bypass the timer switch on the inside, or i would have soldered 3 and 4 together.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the natural position of the timer is either On or Off, when the grey lead is not plugged in.

So: Take off the grey, and plug the red leads in 3 and 5 or in 3 and 4, one of the two combinations should work.

Other options:
You can unplug 3 and 4 and join them together using a male-male piece of alloy of the same size as the jumper input. otherwise you can solder them together, the two red wires, outside of the timer. you could look for a thermostat module instead with some temp controls, and switch it around. you can also unscrew the module, crack it open, and block the mechanism on.

If you don't like soldering, it should be fine to connect together the two red wires using a wire connector, or to tie them together with a threaded copper wire, unsheathed and heavily wrapped in wire and then in 10 layers of of electrical tape, very securely. and check that it doesnt get hot by putting wax on it.